# Massive cryptic error in custom switch function

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++17, boost-hana

I am trying to write an any-value switch based on the `any` type switch example in [the boost hana manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-quickstart-any).

I have done this before with success, but just can not seem to get it done now.

I really want to just figure out what the hell is wrong with my solution, so without further ado:

```
struct default_val{
    constexpr bool operator ==(const auto&) const noexcept{ return false; }
    constexpr bool operator !=(const auto&) const noexcept{ return true; }

    constexpr bool operator ==(default_val) const noexcept{ return true; }
    constexpr bool operator !=(default_val) const noexcept{ return false; }
};

template<typename Fn>
auto default_(Fn fn){
    return hana::make_pair(default_val{}, fn);
}

template<typename Val, typename Fn>
auto case_(Val val, Fn fn){
    return hana::make_pair(val, fn);
}

template<typename Val, typename Default>
decltype(auto) process(Val&&, Default &&def){
    return hana::second(std::forward<Default>(def))();
}

template<typename Val, typename Default, typename Case, typename ... Rest>
decltype(auto) process(Val &&val, Default &&def, Case &&cas, Rest &&... rest){
    if(std::forward<Val>(val) == hana::first(std::forward<Case>(cas)))
        return hana::second(std::forward<Case>(cas))();
    else
        return process(std::forward<Val>(val), std::forward<Default>(def), std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}

template<typename Val>
auto switch_(Val val){
    return [val](auto ... cases){
        auto cases_ = hana::make_tuple(cases...);

        auto default_ = hana::find_if(cases_, [](const auto &c){
            return
                hana::type_c<default_val> ==
                hana::type_c<std::decay_t<decltype(hana::first(c))>>;
        });

        static_assert(default_ != hana::nothing);

        auto rest_ = hana::filter(cases_, [](const auto &c){
            return
                hana::type_c<default_val> !=
                hana::type_c<std::decay_t<decltype(hana::first(c))>>;
        });

        return hana::unpack(rest_, [&](const auto &... rest){
            return process(val, default_, rest...);
        });
    }
}
```

This is supposed to be used like the `any` example, but with values:

```
#include "myswitch.hpp"

int main(){
    std::string input;

    std::cin >> input;

    switch_(input)(
        case_("yowza", []{ std::cout << "where's the enthusiasm?\n"; }),
        case_("Yowza", []{ std::cout << "wat2hek\n"; }),
        case_("YOWZA!", []{ std::cout << "HooRah!\n"; }),

        default_([]{ std::cout << "Hello, World!\n"; })
    );
}
```

But I get a veeeery long and veeeery cryptic error about the use of `hana::find_if_t::operator()(Xs&&, Pred&&)` before deduction of `auto` when assigning `default_` in `switch_`.

Can somebody point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Please add the actual error. Also, it would be helpful if you would reduce your example program - the error is in your `find_if` itself. So everything past that statement, for instance, isn't relevant to your problem.

Comment: @Barry I'm really not sure that it is tho, the error is HUGE. but I will add it (unedited) if it helps.

Comment: @Barry Here's a pastebin link, it's just not worth putting on here. Templates tend to do that to GCC (even still). https://pastebin.com/QBcKbDcK

Comment: @CoffeeandCode No, copy it into a code block.  Just prefix with `>` followed by ... 5 or 6 spaces ... to get it formatted right (It will show up as a quote-of-code).  We'll have scrollbars and everything and it will show up in searches and it won't depend on pastebin being available and all good stuff.

Comment: @Yakk yeah, but the error long surpasses the character limit of stackoverflow. Also I would usually paste the whole thing, highlight it, then hit Ctrl+K: it's much easier.

Comment: @JasonRice I changed it to compare the types inside of the predicates, it has exactly the same errors. I presume the `constexpr` comparison methods of the `default_val` satisfy that requirement already.

Comment: Ah. Can we see the first error message at least? The `default_val` comparisons must return `IntegralConstant`

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa370cc6018d0047 for gcc and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffd01a6c9faa4ac1 for clang. Not too difficult to include IYAM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Boost.Hana's manual for predicate (emphasis mine):

> A function called as predicate(k), where k is a key of the structure, and returning whether k is the key of the element being searched for. In the current version of the library, **the predicate has to return an IntegralConstant holding a value that can be converted to bool**.

This is required for predicates used by both `hana::find_if` and `hana::filter`.

For your `default_val` type the implementation could be changed to this:

```
struct default_val {
    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto operator ==(const T&) const noexcept{ return hana::false_c; }
    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto operator !=(const T&) const noexcept{ return hana::true_c; }

    constexpr auto operator ==(default_val) const noexcept{ return hana::true_c; }
    constexpr auto operator !=(default_val) const noexcept{ return hana::false_c; }
};
```

I ran your code with Clang 3.9 and it worked fine with the following additional tweak to unwrap the value in your `default_` optional value.

```
        return hana::unpack(rest_, [&](const auto &... rest){
        return process(val, *default_, rest...);
                         // ^ Note the added dereference operator here
```

Comment: If I compare the **compile-time** value of their **types**, I get the exact same error message.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Do you know what an `IntegralConstant` is?

Comment: You could use `hana::true_c` and `hana::false_c` instead of raw `true` and `false` values.

Comment: @Barry please show me how I can satisfy the concept of `IntegralConstant` more than a `true` or `false` value computed at compile-time. Also, check my edit.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode `bool` does not satisfy `IntegralConstant`

Comment: @Barry wut. that's absurd on so many levels. Also, take a look at the example on the Boost.Hana manual *then* make such assumptions.

Comment: @Barry A boolean value at compile-time is an "`IntegralConstant`" of value `1` or `0`.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode The only thing absurd is your attitude. Grow up. [IntegralConstant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1IntegralConstant.html) is a concept in the Hana universe that means something very specific.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: "integral type" is not the same thing as `hana::IntegralConstant`.

Comment: @Barry I don't know why you would attack me, but all good. I understand what you meant by `IntegralConstant` now. **Anyway** This is really irrelevant when the example from the `any` switch uses the equality operator just as I have edited my question to as well.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo yes, I understand the point after checking the link Barry sent me.

Comment: Thank you so much @JasonRice! I knew it was going to be something banal in the end.